# Unable to post data to MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, angular2-forms

I am unable to make `Post` request to my `MVC controller` from `angular 2 (typescript) service`.

```
export class LeaveService {
constructor(private _http: Http) { }

Add(model) {
    let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type':
        'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let body = JSON.stringify(model);
    return this._http.post('/api/SampleData', body,
        options).toPromise().catch(this.handleErrorPromise);
}
```

MVC controller

```
[HttpPost]
public string Post([FromBody] Leave leave)
{
    Response.StatusCode = 200;

    try
    {

        // some logic

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 400;
        return e.ToString();
    }
    return "OK";
}
```

I have setup break point on my controller but it is actually not hitting.
Where is the mistake?

Comment: can u pls add ```.then((res:Response)=> console.log(res.json())``` after ```.toPromise()``` and before catch and then let us know what u have in console ?

Comment: You don't have the route for your method, inside of HttpPost attribute you can set your route

Comment: Look on your HTTP calls in browser (network tab) to see if the HTTP call is made or not. If the call is made, then you might receive a different error (like 404) or received an server output cached response. If the HTTP call is not made, then you have a problem with your promise.

Comment: How i can fix promise problem?